# Build failed with an exception cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

Today I was installing the software of cordova for implement the code html in an app. First you have to create a  project and a browser.I want to use this also for android so you have to  add android to a platform. In the moment i want to compile this platform i have an error that stop all the compile and i dont know what to do to solve this error.
I´m adding the code error.

```
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\leti\Aplicaciones\PrimeraApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 75

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 30.0.2; minimum version required is 30.0.3.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\leti\Aplicaciones\PrimeraApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\leti\Aplicaciones\PrimeraApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It says it in your error message

```
 > No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 30.0.2; minimum version required is 30.0.3.
```

Update your build tools to 30.0.3